# How to intercept DB-requests? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm regularly facing the following situation; I am working on an existing system built in PHP which does something, actually quite a lot and it's generally consisting of lots of code. Now I have to extend some feature, debug something and need to know how the system interacts with the MySQL-DB. Which requests are executed in what order.

How can I intercept all queries? Something like xdebug_start_trace for The database.

EDIT: There is no centralized handling of DB-requests. You find every kind of request there. So my question is directed towards some logging feature. Basically that should exist, as it is common sense that somthing like that might be useful.

EDIT2: Mario suggested solution which depends on restarting the mysql-deamon ... no can do. More suggestions?

Comment: Is there one class that handles all the MySQL database connectivity?

Comment: I doubt it can be done on the legacy code using raw API functions.

Comment: If the existing code uses mysql_query() directly, than the last resort option would be to try runkit_function_rename() and define a wrapper function that intercepts all calls. Or the even worse alternative: run the socket through netcat|tee|netcat or use a network sniffer.

Comment: only the network-sniffer left ... hmmm ... :-(

Comment: If you have the source code of the program, then you can change what DB to connect to, right? And I guess you also have a valid login to the DB you're connecting to right now. So why don't you just copy the data to a local instance of MySQL which has logging enabled and change the program to use that MySQL server?

Comment: good idea! ... though copying the db will take quite some time I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQLs "general query log" by starting `mysqld` with a `--log=fn` parameter first.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: I **fear** that's what I was searching for, cause it solves the problem but I can't apply it cause I have no access to the DB and can't restart it with this option :-/

Comment: @Raffael1984: That's what I expected to be the hurdled there. Then your only other option is to make a temporary modification of the application, and search-and-replace `mysql_query(` with `mysql_query_(` to add a reliable wrapper function and custom log support.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going through PDO you can extend it to log or echo query strings.

```
<?php
class PDODebug extends PDO
{
    public function exec ($statement)
    {
        var_dump ($statement); // Or log to a file or use firePHP to log to the console
        return (parent::exec ($statement));
    }
    public function query ($statement)
    {
        var_dump ($statement); // Or log to a file or use firePHP to log to the console
        return (parent::query ($statement));
    }
}
?>
```

Now in your code create a new PDODebug where you would create a PDO and queries performed through it will be logged.  If you're using a different OO database interface (like MySQLI) you should be able to do something similar.

If you're using a non-OO db access layer (like the mysql_* functions) you'll need to insert an echo or var_dump or whatever before every use of a mysql function.

Comment: the system really is huge and there is no centralized db-handling. so any kind of extending-classes-solution would be way more complex then just having the DB dump the queries in some text-file