# Watching function call

Tags: php

Is there a way to trace all calls to a certain function?

The purpose is to plug-in a debug function when "listening" to a function call.

For example, I will say "listen to all calls to `mysqli_query()`", so I can send the function name (and perhaps the arguments) to a debug/log function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898393/how-to-intercept-db-requests-mysql

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to intercept calls to arbitrary functions for logging.

However, the [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) debugging suite may be able to help you with its [execution trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) functionality. You'll be able to log both function calls and the arguments involved.

Comment: Wouldn't something like [XDebug function trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) work?